# Typegoose props not saving

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

I'm having a problem using typegoose,
I have class like:

```
class UserType1 extends Typegoose
      implements User{
    @prop({required: true, unique: true})
    _username: string | undefined;
    @prop({required: true})
    _password: string | undefined;

    constructor(username:string, password: string){
      this._username = username;
      this._password = password;
    }
    
    async saveToDB(): Promis<void>{ // This method is refrenced inside User Interface
       const model: ModelType<UserType1> = getModelForClass(UserType1);
       await model.create(this);
    }

    <Other methods inside class>
}
```

Then I use the above code sequence like this:

```
  const u: User = new UserType1("username", "password");
  u.saveToDB();
```

then, a new record is saved inside *UserType1* collection,
but it's empty. non of the _username, _password or other props are saved inside the record. Inside of it there's only *_id* and a variable called "__v" (which I don't know where it's come from.

Comment: you are using an unmaintained version of typegoose, please upgrade to an later version (7.3.1 is currently the latest)

Comment: Updated my typegoose from _7.3.0_ to _7.3.1_, nothing changed.

Comment: sorry, i guessed it was an unmaintained version, because this example uses many old things, like `extends Typegoose` which got deprecated in 6.0 and removed in 7.0 and trying to use an constructor, which never gets executed in typegoose (if you use the model)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that extends Typegoose was deprecated, could you please point me to the newest Typegoose docs? Because I saw this kind of usage in github and thought it was the right practice. p.s: Constructor is never executes automatically, I use it to create a new object and inject values into class fields.

Comment: the latest docs are: https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So I left my code and started a new clean one, and It was working perfectly,
so I started investigating the difference between codes until I found out this small problem with importing packages, and it was unrelated to my code:
Instead of doing

```
import {prop} from "@typegoose/typegoose"
```

I was doing:

```
import {prop} from "typegoose"
```

Since it didn't give me any warning a worked without errors, I never realized this was the problem.
Hope this he

Answer (score 0):

from what i got as an answer in the comments about not using an unmaintained version, i would recommend to write your example in this way:

```
class UserType1 implements User {
  @prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  public _username!: string;
  @prop({ required: true })
  public _password!: string;

  static async default(this: ReturnModelType<typeof UserType1>, username: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.create({ _username: username, _password: password });
  }

  // <Other methods inside class>
}

const UserModel = getModelForClass(UserType1);

// somewhere in an async code block
await UserModel.default("user1", "somePassword");
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that was because of my example here. I have ```this.``` in my code.

Comment: @MohamadChaman-Motlagh updated the answer to reflect your comments

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't solve my problem. I don't know what's wrong about my code...

Comment: @MohamadChaman-Motlagh then i dont really understand your problem, i made this example removing deprecated things / unsupported things (`extends Typegoose`, constructor) and changed the types to the proper types, and if you mean to re-fetch the model *inside* the function, with this function it is unsupported because it will give you "duplicate model" errors (from mongoose)